# Internal Server Error after deploying node js app for update data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem with deploying my node js app when a user would like to update its profile data it displays Internal Server Error the same thing goes with reset password in dashboard. It seems to be weird since it works locally well without any problems.
it works flawless except updating data.

I should add that I have deployed it on Atlas could MongoDB and it turned back with MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command 
[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4hlc.png)

Following is a part of the code

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const objectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const passport = require('passport');

router.get('/profileEdition', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('profileEdition', {
        username: req.user.username,
        email: req.user.email,
        fullName: req.user.fullName,
        ostan: req.user.ostan,
        shahr: req.user.shahr,
        addressOne: req.user.addressOne,
        addressTwo: req.user.addressTwo,
        postalCode: req.user.postalCode
    });
});

router.post('/profileEdition', function(req, res){
    var item = {
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    ostan: req.body.ostan,
    shahr: req.body.shahr,
    addressOne: req.body.addressOne,
    addressTwo: req.body.addressTwo,
    postalCode: req.body.postalCode,
    email: req.body.email
    };

    const fullName = req.body.fullName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const postalCode = req.body.postalCode;
    const ostan = req.body.ostan;
    const shahr = req.body.shahr;
    const addressOne = req.body.addressOne;

    req.check('fullName', 'نام خود را وارد کنید.').notEmpty();
    req.check('ostan', 'استان محل زندگی خود را وارد کنید.').notEmpty();
    req.check('shahr', 'شهر محل زندگی خود را وارد کنید.').notEmpty();
    req.check('email', 'ایمیل وارد شده صحیح نمیباشد.').isEmail();
    req.check('postalCode', 'کد پستی درست وارد نشده است.').isNumeric();
    req.check('postalCode', 'کد پستی ۱۰ رقم می باشد.').isLength({max: 10});
    req.check('postalCode', 'کد پستی ۱۰ رقم می باشد.').isLength({min: 10});

let errors = req.validationErrors();

 const _id = objectID(req.session.passport.user);
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {

      if(errors){
    res.render('profileEdition', {
        errors: errors
    });
} else {

    assert.equal(null, err);

        db.collection('users').updateOne({_id}, {$set: item}, {runValidators: true}, function(err, result) {

      assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log('Items Updated');
        res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
        db.close();

    });
    }
});
req.flash('successMessages', 'اطلاعات اکانت شما با موفقیت بروزرسانی شد.');
});
```

would be immensely grateful for everyone's help.

Comment: Did you check the username that you've used to authenticate to MongoDB hosted in Atlas cloud (user & password you've used in connection string) has rights to update docs in a collection ? login to atlas cloud portal & in **DataBase Access** tab check that users permissions. Just in case if you've two different servers one local MongoDB server & another Atlas cloud MongoDB server then you need to create user in Atlas to access DB hosted in Atlas..

Comment: Thanks for your reply I do not have any problems with login, log out, register or hash password. It only gives back err when a User wants to update its info.

Comment: So does any of `login, log out, register or hash password` operations write data to same collection of update operation or at least any collection in your DB ?

Comment: Yes I can see the records in my collection.

Comment: Do you mean your node code with same MongoDB user is able to write data to collections ?

Comment: I clearly see the data coming into my collection when I register.

Comment: I just editted my post with a picture of the err my db hosted in Atlas mongoDB